# How can I move the binary point in the string so that there is only single 1 left before it?

Tags: java, binary, bit-shift

```
    double num=1234.1034;

    int decimalpart=(int)num;
    double fractionalpart=num-dpart;
    String binaryNumber=decToBinary(decimalpart)+"."+
    decFracToBin(String.valueOf(fractionalpart));
```

- How can I normalize this "binNumber" String?
  The out put I am getting for this **binNumber** is :10011010010.00011010011110000

Comment: How do you want to achieve this, by working on the double or by working on the string? The two methods may not be equivalent due to precision issues.

Comment: By working on the string,  @MargaretBloom

Comment: A sketch may be this pseudo code `normalize(dec, fra) -> s = dec + fra; i = s.indexOf('1'); if (i >= 0) return s.substring(i, i+1) + "." + s.substring(i+2); else return "0";`. Watch for edge cases and correct it if needed.